# Does reshuffling my train/test split to avoid collinearity cause bias?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, inference

Suppose I have a categorical variable with 3 levels. Levels $A$ and $B$ account for 49.5% of my data each, and level $C$ for the rest. Sometimes, when I split my data into training and test sets, it happens that all the level $C$ data is in the test split. That means that the categorical variable now becomes collinear with the intercept in a linear model. My plan is to keep shuffling the train and test sets until the training set contains some level $C$.

Will this cause any bias in my model?

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a common problem. You might want to take a look at stratified shuffling, which takes into account the label of the data during shuffling (for example StratifiedShuffleSplit in scikit-learn). The situation you describe indicates a small sample. You might want to look at k-fold cross validation to make better use of your data (StratifiedKFold in scikit-learn).